# 'error: sampler arrays indexed with non-constant expressions are forbidden in GLSL 1.30 and later' in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am writing the following fragment shader for a game engine:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform vec4 colour;
uniform vec2 light_pos;

in DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec2 uv;
    float tid;
    vec4 color;
} fs_in;

uniform sampler2D textures[32];

void main()
{
    float intensity = 1.0 / length(fs_in.position.xy - light_pos);

    vec4 texColor = fs_in.color;

    if(fs_in.tid > 0.0){
        int tid = int(fs_in.tid + 0.5);
        texColor = texture(textures[tid], fs_in.uv);
    }

    color = texColor * intensity;
}
```

The line `texColor = texture(textures[tid], fs_in.uv);` causes the 'sampler arrays indexed with non-constant expressions are forbidden in GLSL 1.30 and later' expression when compiling the shader.

The vertex shader if needed is:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uv;
layout (location = 2) in float tid;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 color;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);

out DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec2 uv;
    float tid;
    vec4 color;
} vs_out;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix * position;
    vs_out.position = ml_matrix * position;
    vs_out.uv = uv;
    vs_out.tid = tid;
    vs_out.color = color;
}
```

Comment: what is unclear about that

Comment: How would i go about solving it?

Comment: So how did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

In GLSL 3.3 indexing for sampler arrays is only allowed by an [integral constant expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Integral_constant_expression) (see [GLSL 3.3 Spec, Section 4.1.7](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf)).

In more modern version, starting from GLSL 4.0 it is allowed to index sampler arrays by [dynamic uniform expressions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression) (see [GLSL 4.0 Spec, Section 4.1.7](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.00.pdf))

What you actually are trying is to index the array by a varying which is simply impossible. If it is absolutely unavoidable to do that, you could pack the 2d textures into a 2d array texture or into a 3d texture and use the index to address the layer (or the 3rd dimension) of the texture.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in line `texColor = texture(textures[tid], fs_in.uv)` the sampler array `texturues` is given a non constant index.

The easy work-around it is to use a large switch statement to replace the line  `texColor = texture(textures[tid], fs_in.uv)` so that the texture array can be assessed by a constant number. For example, you may write something like this:

```
uniform sampler2D textures[32];

void main()
{
    float intensity = 1.0 / length(fs_in.position.xy - light_pos);

    vec4 texColor = fs_in.color;

    if(fs_in.tid > 0.0){

        // texColor = texture(textures[tid], fs_in.uv)
        // replace with large switch

        int tid = int(fs_in.tid + 0.5);
        switch (int(tid)){
            case 0:
                texColor = texture(textures[0], fs_in.uv);
                break;
            case 1:
                texColor = texture(textures[1], fs_in.uv);
                break;
            case 2:
                texColor = texture(textures[2], fs_in.uv);
                break;
    
            // repeat for all textures
        }
    }

    color = texColor * intensity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Switching to a newer version (#460 to be precise) worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this issue by using a little code-generation:

in Javascript it looks like this:

```
const maxNumTextures = 32;
function makeSwitchCase (i) {
return `
  case ${i}:
    sum += texture2D(texturesArray[${i}], vUv);
    break;
`
};

const fragmentShader = `
#define numTextures ${maxNumTextures}

uniform sampler2D baseTexture;
uniform sampler2D texturesArray[numTextures];

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  vec4 base = texture2D(baseTexture, vUv);
  vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);

  for (int i = 0; i < numTextures; ++i) {
    switch(i) {
      // we are not allowed to use i as index to access texture in array in current version of GLSL
      ${new Array(maxNumTextures)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, i) => makeSwitchCase(i))
        .join('')}
      default: break;
    }
  }

  gl_FragColor = base + sum;
}
`;
```

Note: we use ` to start and stop multiline strings in JS and ${some_value} to provide value for template

Comment: This doesn't solve ops problem since you aren't indexing the texture with a varying.